# JavaScript CSV Export

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

I'm generating CSV file via this code

```
export default function (name, data) {
  if (!data || !Array.isArray(data)) {
    return
  }
  name = name.length ? `${name}.csv` : 'export.csv'
  var csvData = new Blob([data.map(e => e.join(',')).join('\n')], { type: 'text/csv' })
  var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData)
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.setAttribute('href', csvUrl)
  link.setAttribute('download', name)
  document.body.appendChild(link) // Required for FF
  link.click()
  document.body.removeChild(link)
}
```

But in Excel it opens row one column.

Is it possible to generate csv file that will show correct in Excel?

Comment: How your data looks like? I think that there is some mistake there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import the file in Excel and choose `,` as separator instead of just opening the file.

---

Another option is to write the following as the first line (Excel specific):

```
sep=,
```

This will force Excel to use `,` as the separator.

---

A third option is to use a different separator like `TAB` or `;`. How Excel opens this depends on the (locale?) settings of the system.

Comment: it works but in other table redactors `sep=,` shows as a first-line, any solutions for this issue?

Comment: Yes, this is Excel specific. Another option is to use a different separator like `TAB` or `;`. How Excel opens this depends on the (locale?) settings of the system.